# JQuery Selector start with strange behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

in our code i found the following line :
`$("[^unitRow_]:checked")` it works ok but  as i know it should be `$("[id^=unitRow_]:checked")` 
without `:checked` i got syntax error without `[^unitRow_]` i got some additional values  can somebody explain to me how it works ?

```
$("[^unitRow_]:checked") returns
[
<input type=​"checkbox" disabled=​"disabled" checked=​"checked" class=​"global-item-selectAll" id=​"unitRow_x88ce13f5asda6f6_x5e8dasdaa60d76533" name=​"unitRow_x88ce13f5075a26f6_x5e8cc08dsad533" qualification=​"x5e8cc08a6sdad3" unitid=​"x88ce13f5075a26f6">​
]
$(":checked")
[
<input type=​"checkbox" disabled=​"disabled" checked=​"checked" class=​"global-item-selectAll" id=​"unitRow_x88ce13f507as5a26f6_x5e8cc0dsa8a60d76533" name=​"unitRow_x88ce13fgfdg5075a26f6_x5e8cc08a6asd0d76533" qualification=​"x5e8fecc08a60d76533" unitid=​"x88ce13vref5075a26f6">​
, 
<option alt=​"Please select" selected=​"selected" style=​"width:​110px;​" title=​"Please select" value>​Please select​</option>​
, 
<option alt=​"Please select" style=​"width:​110px;​" title=​"Please select" value>​Please select​</option>​
, 
<option value=​"8" selected=​"selected">​Sep​</option>​
, 
<option value=​"2011" selected=​"selected">​2011​</option>​
]
```

Thanks .

Comment: All the explanation you need is here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/. If you can show us the HTML you're using this with we may be better able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$('[id^="unitRow_"]:checked')
```

[image]

Comment: I know that [id^="unitRow_"] is correct but why my selector also work

Comment: @user872761 if you write `[^unitRow_]` you are actually telling : any attribte which his value starts with `^unitRow_`

Answer (score 1):

To combine more selector you could take a look at

- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

You simply write them after each other
   `$('input[id][name$="man"]')`

The one which is used in your code is the Attribute Starts With selector:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

I guess all what it does is it takes everything that has an attribute that starts with "unitRow_" and "selects" it